# Java lang Assertion Error Unexpected method call BookService findAll()

Tags: java, spring, mocking

Everything seems to be right in my test but I keep getting this error on the book service call to find all 
i have mocked the class i am using correctly .

```
@Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "admin", roles={"ADMIN"})
    public void bookRemoveTest() throws Exception {
        Book book = new Book();
        List<Book> expectedBookList = createBookList(10);

         /* expect */ bookService.removeOne(anyLong());
        EasyMock.expectLastCall();
        replay(bookService);
        bookService.removeOne(anyLong());

       // Assert.assertEquals("expectedBookList", bookService.findAll());
        expect(bookService.findAll()).andReturn(expectedBookList);

        mockMvc
                .perform(post("/book/remove")
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .param("id","12345678" ))

                 .andExpect(model().attributeExists("bookList"))
                .andExpect(view().name("bookList"))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
                .andReturn();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call replay method after you finished the setup.
So please move the `expect(bookService.findAll())` call before the `replay(bookService)` and it should be good.

Comment: i did that and i got

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call BookService.removeOne(12345678):
    BookService.removeOne(<any>): expected: 1, actual: 2
    BookService.findAll(): expected: 1, actual: 0
@Admit

Comment: If you check your code - you are calling removeOne in the test code just after replay (1) and inside your rest code (2). Also you are not calling findAll at all.